# How to find the min and max of each group with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how I could do this in SQL. I have a table with the following columns in the Customer table - (Customer_Id, Gender, Birthday). Question is - I need to find the earliest and latest born, by Gender. Essentially Min and Max by different groups.

```
123 M   2017-07-05 00:00:00.000
345 M   2016-08-01 00:00:00.000
555 F   2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
567 F   2015-02-07 00:00:00.000
789 F   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
111 F   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
188 M   2008-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

The result set should look like this

```
188     M       2008-09-01 00:00:00.000
123     M       2017-07-05 00:00:00.000
111     F       2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
567     F       2015-02-07 00:00:00.000
```

I could do 4 `UNION`S and figure it out that way but that would be inefficient.

Here is what I came up with but this is not going to work either. How do I do it for MAX groups also in one query?

```
    select a.Customer_id, a.gender, b.min_birthday
    from(
    select gender, min(birthday) min_birthday
    from Sales..Customer group by gender) b join Sales..Customer a on b.gender = a.gender 
    and b.min_birthday = a.birthday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select customer_id, gender, birthday
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by birthday) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by birthday desc) as seqnum_desc
      from customer c
     ) c
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you want ties.

That said, with an index on `(gender, birthday)` and `(gender, birthday desc)` (both indexes may no longer be needed if the optimizer has improved), the `union all` approach should perform very well:

```
select c.*
from ((select top (1) c.*
       from customer c
       where gender = 'M'
       order by birthday
      ) union all
      (select top (1) c.*
       from customer c
       where gender = 'F'
       order by birthday
      ) union all
      (select top (1) c.*
       from customer c
       where gender = 'M'
       order by birthday desc
      ) union all
      (select top (1) c.*
       from customer c
       where gender = 'F'
       order by birthday desc
      )
     ) c;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you. The ranking function will only give me min birthdays for the two gender groups(because you are retrieving only the first rank). How do I retrieve the max birthdays, given their ranks will always be dynamic?

Comment: @peppa . . . That was a typo.  I put `desc` in the name, but not in the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Actually one `UNION ALL` is enough :)

```
select gender, min(birthday) birthday, 'MIN' Aggregate
from Sales..Customer group by gender
union all
select gender, max(birthday), 'MAX'
from Sales..Customer group by gender
```

But better performacne would be with:

```
select gender, min(birthday), max(birthday)
from Sales..Customer group by gender
```

But result will be slightly different from desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.* from Customer c
where not exists (
  select 1 from Customer
  where gender = c.gender and birthday < c.birthday
) or not exists (
  select 1 from Customer
  where gender = c.gender and birthday > c.birthday
)
order by c.gender, c.birthday
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c11c1c62646a2ea67ab5017d34ba9090).
Results:

```
> id  | gender | birthday           
> :-- | :----- | :------------------
> 111 | F      | 01/01/2000 00:00:00
> 567 | F      | 07/02/2015 00:00:00
> 188 | M      | 01/09/2008 00:00:00
> 123 | M      | 05/07/2017 00:00:00
```